# UWP TextBox maximum lines limitation?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps

When I load four megabytes of text into TextBox only first 11300 lines
are shown. The rest is blank. But even though it is blank 
I can still scroll trough it and can select text. 
When I paste it elsewhere text is present.
It's just that the text doesn't show past 11300 lines.
Is there some way to fix this problem?

[Here is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3nCB.png)

Here is how i declare it in xaml:

```
   <RichEditBox 
            x:Name="ContentBox" 
            x:FieldModifier="public" 
            Grid.Row="0"
            KeyDown="Tb_KeyDown"
            GotFocus="Content_gotfocus"
            Loaded="Content_gotfocus"
            AcceptsReturn="True" 
            TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            IsSpellCheckEnabled="False"
            IsTextPredictionEnabled="False"
            TextReadingOrder="UseFlowDirection"
            FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
            TextAlignment="Left"
            >
        </RichEditBox>
```

OR

```
 <TextBox 
            x:Name="ContentBox" 
            x:FieldModifier="public" 
            Grid.Row="0"
            AcceptsReturn="True" 
            KeyDown="Tb_KeyDown"
            GotFocus="Content_gotfocus"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" 
            ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="True" 
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
            TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
            IsSpellCheckEnabled="False"
            IsTextPredictionEnabled="False"
            Loaded="Content_gotfocus"

            TextReadingOrder="UseFlowDirection"
            FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
            TextAlignment="Left" LayoutUpdated="content_box_updated"
            />
```

Comment: You may rather use [`RichEditBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/richtextbox-overview). Maybe it would be better for such big amounts of data.

Comment: Can you tell me please how to set it up because , by default RichEditBox has the same problem.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a line limit per se.  When I looked at sqlite3.c amalgamation just now I got to line 12,035 before it showed this behavior (it's a good file to break things with because it's 200,000 lines plus).  You can still select the text after it (and copy it), just not see it.  I've written a control in win2d to display millions of lines but making it an actual textbox is a whole other ballgame.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code and reproduced your issue. The cause of the issue is both of the `RichEditBox` and `TextBox` will use the `ScrollViewer` control to scroll the content. But there is the limitation of max content that can be used in the `scrollview`. And it is by design for keeping the performance of control.
If you want to display the rest of content. you could intercept the remaining content based on the maximum line number and display the remaining content in the other `RichEditBox/TextBox`.

Comment: You'd probably know better than I would but the reason I question this is because you can continue scrolling through the entirety of the text, you just can't see the text (but it's there in some capacity because you can select it and copy it/paste it somewhere else).